# How to partition in Bigquery to be able to access latest state of each record

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a big query table where i am streaming data from pubsub. how to partition to be able to access the latest state of any record. e.g User-1 dimensions has changed 5 times over last one year and how do i maintain the is_current_record = Y flag so that i can partition data with this flag. thanks

Comment: Please provide more details i.e. sample data and the desired output

Comment: Cant help without more details. But take a look in the new CDC feature: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-data-capture